# Thank you E-mail

Tags: british-english

I have received one e-mail from I.T with some attachment to show how to setup e-mail account in outlook. I have finished setup and now the e-mail is working.

Now I want to reply him but what is the correct way to reply?

"I have setup the e-mail account according to attached files and it is working now. Thanks for your support"

Or

"It is working now and thanks for your support"

Comment: Well done for sending a thank-you email! It is often forgotten.

Comment: @oeekelens I agree! I find it rather rude not to reply to emails. So many people don't! I just see it as common etiquette.

Comment: Not remotely sure *where* this question would be on topic, but the question seems a sincere and meaningful question, so I'm in favor of just answering it. As luck would have it, Dog Lover has provided a good one.

Comment: @DogLover Part of the problem might be with (semi-)automated support/ticketing systems, which often end with something along the lines of "_If this didn't resolve the issue, please reply to this email keeping the subject line intact_" ... tending to imply that you shouldn't reply if it worked (as it will re-open the support ticket).

Comment: I can tell you that it should not be "solved kthx". Yes, that is an actual reply I've gotten when I worked support.

Answer (score 2):

I like the first one. It just needs to read:

> I have **set up** the e-mail account according to **the** attached files and it is working now. Thanks for your support.

Comment: I'd prefer to know that something I suggested helped you, but thanks would be appreciated, regardless.